# stripping url and email

Tags: regex, email, url

I have to strip the URL from a form field I have. I found this regex online but it doesn't really work that well

```
@?(https?:\/\/)?([\da-z\.-]+)\.([a-z\.]{2,6})([\/\w \.-]*)*\/?
```

It does strip all the URLs including the `@` symbol from emails (which I want) but it also strips anything with a `.` and 2 characters afterwards like my email: `bia.migueis@gmail.com` it matches the whole thing and after stripping it returns empty. I need to strip:

```
http://www.example.com
https://www.example.com
www.example.com
example.com

bia.migueis@gmail.com --> bia.migueis
```

should be left

Comment: What programming language you are on?

Comment: coldfusion. just using ReReplaceNoCase

Answer (score 1, accepted):

bia.migueis, you just want the url?

This cleaned up version of your regex will capture the url in Group 1:

```
(?:@|https?://)?([\da-z.-]+\.[a-z.]{2,6})\b(?!@)
```

**Input:**

```
http://www.example.com
https://www.example.com
www.example.com
example.com
bia.migueis@gmail.com --> 
bia.migueis
```

**Group 1 Captures:**

```
www.example.com
www.example.com
www.example.com
example.com
gmail.com
```

Looking at your tags, I see that you are mostly interested in Java and Javascript.

Group 1 in Java:

```
String ResultString = null;
try {
    Pattern regex = Pattern.compile("(?:@|https?://)?([\\da-z.-]+\\.[a-z.]{2,6})\\b(?!@)");
    Matcher regexMatcher = regex.matcher(subjectString);
    if (regexMatcher.find()) {
        ResultString = regexMatcher.group(1);
    } 
} catch (PatternSyntaxException ex) {
    // Syntax error in the regular expression
}
```

Group 1 in Javascript:

```
var myregexp = /(?:@|https?:\/\/)?([\da-z.-]+\.[a-z.]{2,6})\b(?!@)/;
var match = myregexp.exec(subject);
if (match != null) {
    result = match[1];
} else {
    result = "";
}
```

Comment: this ALMOST works. when testing with bar.ba@test.co.uk it matches the first part (bar.ba) and the second part(@test.com.uk). I'm using regexr to test these

Comment: @bia.migueis Thanks for that edge case, added a negative lookahead to fix that. Let me know if this does it.

Comment: perfect thanks :D also much cleaner than all my normal regexes lol

Comment: @bia.migueis Glad it worked, thanks for your feedback, nice talking to you.

Answer (score 0):

You can add a NOT @ sign at the end.

```
@?(https?:\/\/)?([\da-z\.-]+)\.([a-z\.]{2,6})([\/\w \.-]*)*\/?[^@]
```

Comment: this ALMOST works. when testing with bia.migueis@gmail.com it matches the first part (bia.migueis) and the second part(@gmail.com). I'm using regexr to test these

Answer (score 0):

I mixed the answer from Ld00d and zx81 and got it to work just like i want it

```
(?:@|https?:\/\/)?([\da-z.-]+\.[a-z.]{2,6})\b[^@]
```